# set wiki page as my home page on redmine 3.2.1

Tags: redmine, wiki

I googled much for find how to set wiki page as my home page on remine version 3.2.1, but as per i get solutions changes in route.rb file.

I tried but dont seems any effect. there is any other change required in route.rb or how can I debug where is issue, because of I not know much ruby its much complicated for me how we debug and go ahead and set wiki page as home.

root :to => 'wiki#show', :project_id =>'' ,:as => 'home'

after this line added still i dont get the wiki page as per project name as default home page,

also commented below line: root :to => 'welcome#index', :as => 'home'

need to change anything else on route.rb, i dont catch where is the issue, because of i am not having knowledge its much complicated me to debug how can we set wiki page as home page in redmine 3.2.x version.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to accomplish this recently. I eventually settled for this:

1. Install Redmine Landing Page plugin: http://www.redmine.org/plugins/landing_page
2. Update users' preferences for that plugin:

   UPDATE users u, members m
   SET u.landing_page='http://www.example.com'
   WHERE m.user_id=u.id
   AND m.project_id=xx AND u.status=1 AND u.type='User';

Comment: ok thanks,

that is for redmine version 3.2.1 ??

and how can i do this step there is not any settings for this plugin on administrator.

Update users' preferences for that plugin:

UPDATE users u, members m SET u.landing_page='http://www.example.com' WHERE m.user_id=u.id AND m.project_id=xx AND u.status=1 AND u.type='User';

Comment: and right now my my page is set as default home page.

that mean my home and my page both is same,

and we want to set now home as my one wiki page.